# What is the best Black reply to 1. d4 in regards to getting an open game?

Tags: opening, theory, 1.d4

What is a good reply to 1.d4 that will give me an open game?

Comment: What do you mean by "open game"? Usually the term "open game" refers to the double king pawn opening 1.e4 e5. It is very unlikely to transpose into an open game after 1.d4 but it is possible, e.g. 1.d4 Nc6 2.e4 e5 3.Nf3 transposing to the Scotch Game 1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.d4.

Answer (score 3):

**1...d5**. Tarrasch defense and, in general, **c5** ideas practically always give an open game. As long as you can get in the move **c5** with Black, you have excellent practical chances of achieving an open game.

Some sample variations -

```
  [FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]

  1. d4 d5 2. c4 (2. Nc3 Nf6 3. Bg5 (3. Bf4 e6 4. Nf3 c5) 3... c5) 
 (2. Nf3 e6 3. g3 (3. e3 c5) 3... c5 4. Bg2 Nc6 5. O-O Nf6 6. c4 dxc4 
  7. Qa4 Bd7 8. Qxc4 b5 9. Qd3 Rc8) 2... e6 3. Nc3 c5 4. cxd5 
 (4. Nf3 Nf6 5. e3 Nc6 6. a3 a6 7. dxc5 Bxc5 8. b4 Bd6) 4... exd5 
  5. Nf3 Nc6 6. g3 Nf6 7. Bg2 Be7 8. O-O O-O 9. Bg5 cxd4 10. Nxd4 h6 11. Be3 Re8
```

Comment: I've been playing the Benko Gambit lately and been happy with most the positions I find myself in. It has c5, as you may already know. S

Comment: But that's different because there white keep the game closed by pushing d4-d5. In the Tarrasch black blocks the d-pawn first, then attacks it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a recent book on 1.d4 d5 2.c4 c5 by Alexei Bezgodov. The idea is to liquidate the center pawns and get an open game. Inspired by the book I play it a lot as Black in my online blitz games with good results. Check out https://www.newinchess.com/the-double-queen-s-gambit

Answer (score 0):

I personally like 1. d4 Nf6 because there are much more openings and traps white can use on black if he does 1. d4 d5.(for example Queen's Gambit)
Plus, you can use the Budapest Gambit (which I really like) if the opening is 1. d4 Nf6